# getting error 'Cannot read property 'split' of undefined' when try to read text file

Tags: jquery, get, text-files

I'm trying to read a simple text file line by line. It looks something like this:

```
01040010001000000DEM       PRESIDENTIAL ELECTION     Hillary Clinton   MUNI1   
01040010001000000DEM       PRESIDENTIAL ELECTION     Hillary Clinton   MUNI2
```

I'm using .get to retrieve the file and trying to parse it line by line:

```
$.get('results2016.txt', function(txt) {
    txt = txt.replace("\r\n", "\n"); // Just in case
    var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
    for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
        console.log(lines[i]);
    }
}); //function
```

But I'm getting the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

I added the line about replacing \r\n with \n, but I get the same error.

I'm guessing that the code can't read the line breaks, but why? And what should I do?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: If `txt` is a string, and it has to be if you're calling `.replace()` on it, then calling `txt.responseText` is invalid because that would imply that `txt` is an object...

Comment: @War10ck: OK, I've taken out that line, but I get the same error.

Comment: Add `console.log(txt);` as the first line in the `$.get()` function callback. Then open your console `<F12>` and see what is logged to understand the structure of the data returned. If need be, post it here for additional help. My gut feeling is that you're not getting a `.responseText` property back in your `txt` result. Typically, `.responseText` is part of the native XHR object returned, however I believe jQuery abstracts this away in the callback function unless you pull the third parameter I think?...

Comment: @War10ck: when I console.log(txt), I get the whole file back, line by line.

Comment: In that case keep your first line `txt = txt.replace('\r\n', '\n');` and then change your second line to be `var lines = txt.split('\n');` Remove any reference to the `.responseText` property...

Comment: I used var lines = txt.split("/\n/g"); and that worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127302/discussion-between-lauranms-and-war10ck).